# Upgrading VBA 6->7 causes error: If Exists in Collection

Tags: vba, collections

VBA6 code (Excel) worked great. Upgrade to Office 2010/VBA7, code breaks.

Using code from SO:

[Determining whether an object is a member of a collection in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137845/determining-whether-an-object-is-a-member-of-a-collection-in-vba/991900#991900)

```
Public Function Contains(col As Collection, key As Variant) As Boolean
Dim obj As Variant
On Error GoTo err
    Contains = True
    obj = col(key)
    Exit Function
err:

    Contains = False
End Function
```

I get run-time error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument.

It doesn't make sense to me though because the error occurs on the `obj = col(key)` line which should be covered by the `On Error GoTo err` statement, but it stops.

Other *If X exists in collection* type solutions have the same problem.

Instead of fixing the broken code, what I really need is to be able to see if a record is already set for a collection, if that can be done some other (new) way in VBA7, that would solve the problem as well (I can dream).

Comment: what about solution which is provided in approved answer under the link you've put in your question (looping)...

Comment: As a temporary (?) workaround, I've put in `On Error Resume Next` just before the Collection checking and things seem to work okay, but that makes me nervous.

Comment: This is side-stepping the issue, so not a real answer, but I prefer `Scripting.Dictionary` objects instead, as those have a built-in `.exists()` call. For many of my functions, they seem to run faster as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that if I change specify an object, e.g., a worsheet, it works:

```
Public Function Contains(col As Collection, key As Variant) As Boolean
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

On Error GoTo err
Contains = True
Set ws = col(key)
Exit Function
err:
Contains = False
End Function
```

I call it like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim coll As Collection

Set coll = New Collection
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
coll.Add ws, ws.Name
Next ws
Debug.Print Contains(coll, ActiveSheet.Name)
Debug.Print Contains(coll, "not a worksheet name")
End Sub
```

I get True for the first call and False for the second.

Comment: I think that `Set` key word in your situation is even more crucial than object specification, isn't it? +1 for you anyway :)

Comment: Changing `Dim obj As Variant` and `Dim obj As Excel.Worksheet` did not work either. I tried just your code, and get the same error. Starting to think it's not the code and some other configuration. I did check the references had 4 checked: VBA, Excel 14.0, OLE Automation, Office 14.0

Comment: @KazJaw, Thanks. Seems to me they go hand-in-hand, i.e., you can't set a variant.

Comment: @MECU, Just to clarify, the function didn't work for me with a worksheet until I made the change (Excel 2010). I didn't get the runtime error though, just False no matter what, so it does sound like something else is going on too.

Comment: @DougGlancy Would you suggest using generic `Object` (or some other type) for a more flexible solution (e.g. a Collection of varying types/multiple Collections of different types)? Or would you recommend instead one `Contains` function per Collection type?

Comment: @Gaffi, good question. I try to limit my collections to one type of object, and my answer reflects that. But a generic object works in the function, so I guess you could do that for re-usability with multiple collections of different types.