# excel vba import system.collections.hashmap into a module

Tags: function, excel, import, module, vba

From the inside of my **MS Excel 2010** installation I have opened the **Visual Basic Editor**. (Tab Developer Tools -> Visual Basic)

Inside the **Visual Basic Editor**  i right-clicked into the **Project Window** and created a **module**. (Insert -> Module)

Then i typed the following code into the **Code Window**:

```
Sub myFunction()
    'do some stuff to my table cells, not important
End Sub
```

After coding a lot of things inside the function body, i thought i was in need for a Hashmap, which needs to be accessed inside that given function body. Unfortunately, i **could not import** the class needed by doing this:

```
Imports System.Collections
Sub myFunction()
    'do some stuff to my table cells, not important
End Sub
```

The **error message** appears when launching the module by pressing F5. And it says (translated from geman to english by me): "*Error while Compiling: illegal outside of a procedure"*.

**How is it possible to have something imported in VBA, when the code is structured like above?** I'am usually a **java or python** person.  You can also re-structure the code, if the function still executes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you either use a

**Collection** class

or

**Dictionary** class

---

`Collection` class is *built-in* into VBA so you do not need to add external references to be able to use it. You can simply declare it

```
Dim c as Collection
Set c = new Collection
```

`Collection` exposes 4 methods: `add, count, item, remove` so it may not be sufficient for you.

[`Customizing, expanding Collection class`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373081/how-to-use-the-implements-in-excel-vba/19379641#19379641)

---

If you want to use something like a *HashTable/HashMap* then add references to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` by clicking `Tools` and `References` in the VBE window

then you can use early-binding and intellisense with the `Dictionary` class

```
Dim d as Dictionary
Set d = new Dictionary
```

Or use late-binding

```
Dim d as Object
set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

I would go for the early-binding (first example - adding references to VBA project) so you can use VBA Intellisense.

You can view `Dictionary` or `Collection` class using the Object Browser - simply hit <kbd>F2</kbd> in the VBE window and type in `Dictionary` or `Collection`

[image]

Useful read about the [`Dictionary class`](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/A_3391-Using-the-Dictionary-Class-in-VBA.html)

Comment: Thanks! There seems to be no "contains" method in both classes, but in the Dictionary class there is something similar: the "exists"-method. Can i use that in the same fashion as a "contains"-method ?

Comment: @kiltek check [**`this out`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137845/determining-whether-an-object-is-a-member-of-a-collection-in-vba) - shows how to implement a method to check if a key exists

Comment: The exists function does suit my needs. So when importing something through the excel vba editor i have to do the following "In the vba editor -> Tools -> References -> add needed library". This is not really different from java, but i do not need an extra import.