# vba-variant: how to handle Class vs. primitive types

Tags: vba, object, variant

my function gets a collection and the items may be Objects or primitives
how can I assign the item to a variant?

What I do now looks something like this:

```
Dim vItem As Variant
On Error Resume Next
vItem = oCollection.Item(sKey)
If Err.Number = 91 Then
    Set vItem = oCollection.Item(sKey)
On Error GoTo 0
```

I think it works, but I wonder if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `varType()` function to test the type, alternatively if you are testing for specific types, you could use typeof.

```
        If VarType(oCollection.Item(sKey)) = vbObject Then
           Set vItem = oCollection.Item(sKey)
        Else
            vItem = oCollection.Item(sKey)
        End If
```

Comment: That would work, but I need a solution to use `oCollection.Item(sKey)`. as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137845/determining-whether-an-object-is-a-member-of-a-collection-in-vba) by Mark Nold it is much faster (especially since I will have huge collections)

Comment: How about: `If VarType(oCollection.Item(sKey)) = vbObject`?

Comment: yeah - thanks that works of course (that seemed to easy to me..)

Comment: Is type checking different than `IsObject(oCollection.Item(sKey))` ?

Answer (score 0):

A slight improvement to the answer from @SWa is to create a helper function; this avoids having to copy/paste, for example, the `oCollection.Item(sKey)` part of op's answer.

```
Sub SetThisToThat(ByRef this As Variant, ByRef that As Variant)
    If IsObject(that) Then
        Set this = that
    Else
        this = that
    End If
End Sub
```

Some tests as an example:

```
Function Test()
    Call SetThisToThat(Test, "Function test")
End Function

Sub RunTest()
    MsgBox Test

    Dim s As String
    Call SetThisToThat(s, "Why must it be this hard?")
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

@TmTron should use:

```
Call SetThisToThat(vItem, oCollection.Item(sKey))
```