# Variant but not an Object

Tags: excel, vba, variant

If I know a bit of data is going to be an Object, but I don't know what kind, I can pass it to a function or routine like this:

```
Sub mySubExpectingAnObject(myVal As Object)
```

Which is more explicit than

```
Sub mySubExpectingAnObject(myVal As Variant)
```

And should be preferred even if both work

If instead I know the bit of data is *not* an object, but could be anything else (`Long`, `Double`, `String` etc.), is there any way of `Dim`ing the argument as not an object. E.g

```
Sub mySubExpectingNotAnObject(myVal As NotObject)
```

Since if I use `Variant` here, there will be no automatic anti-object check. Does such a type exist; one that can encapsulate any non-object datatype exclusively? Is there a workaround other than just

```
If isObject(myVal) Then Err.Raise 5
```

or similar?

Comment: This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572437/vba-variant-how-to-handle-class-vs-primitive-types

Comment: Const vbObject = 9 in assoc with ^^ link. But noting your question is **specifically** about Dim not testing ....

Comment: `Variant` exists *specifically* to lift the compile-time type constraints that implicit type conversions don't already mess up... Might as well take a `String`, and convert from there.

Comment: Why does it matter what it's **"not"**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see what's wrong with using a `Variant` and throwing an *invalid procedure call or argument* run-time error 5, which pretty much *literally* says "this procedure was invoked with an invalid argument", given `IsObject(theParameter)` returning `True`.

`Variant` exists *specifically* to lift the compile-time type constraints so that VBA can deal with foreign types such as `IUnknown` and whatnot: there's no way you can use a `Variant` *and* enforce any kind of compile-time check against it - *by definition* a `Variant`'s type is only resolved at run-time.

The idiomatic way to solve this, is to use good, meaningful names for both your procedure and their parameters. Pretty hard to recommend anything with the examples you've got though.

There is no "variant but not an object" type, and you can't use a `Variant` and expect any kind of type validation at compile-time.