# Type mismatch error 13 vba collection

Tags: vba, excel

Why do I get a type mismatch running `sub bar` below in Excel VBA?

```
Sub foo(c As Collection)
    Debug.Print c.Count
End Sub

Sub bar()
    Call foo(Worksheets)
End Sub
```

The code above is a minimal working example intended to focus only on the Type related issues. The origin of this question is that, at some point, the code from [This existence test for a member of a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/991900/414125) worked, but now I get the same type mismatch described in this question.

I wonder what detail is causing the type confusion. Is `Worksheets` not a `Collection`?

Comment: If you're running that in Excel VBA then why is this question tagged with VB.NET but not VBA?

Comment: Oddly enough, I checked the tags before posting. They were `excel`, `vba`, and `excel-vba`. I fixed them back to those values. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: instead of declaring c as collection, try declaring it as a variant

Comment: But if you declare as `Variant` you can't use the methods from Collection. Isn't `Worksheets` a `Collection`?