# VBA EXCEL adding array members of specific column to collection for counting unique values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, count, unique

I need a public function to get array and counts values in specific column.
I wrote the following and recives subscription out of range message.

```
Public Function CountUarrcol(inarr() As Variant, colidx As Integer) As Long
 Dim col As New Collection
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim element As Variant

 For i = 0 To UBound(inarr, colidx)
    For Each element In inarr(i + 1, colidx)
        col.Add Item:=CStr(element.value), Key:=CStr(element.value)
    Next
 Next i
 CountUarrcol = col.Count   End Function
```

Comment: Is i + 1 putting you beyond the UBound of inarr during the loop?

Comment: Why do you have two loops?  How are you passing `inarr` to your function?  What line does your code stop on when you get the error?

Comment: i revised this piece to following: <code> 'Public Function CountUarrcol(inarr As Variant, colidx As Integer) As Long
     Dim col As New Collection
     Dim i As Integer
     Dim element As Variant

     For Each element In inarr
         col.Add Item:=element, Key:=element
     Next
     CountUarrcol = col.Count
End Function' </code>

Comment: now error is 457 the key is already associated with an element of collection

Comment: See here [determining-whether-an-object-is-a-member-of-a-collection-in-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137845/determining-whether-an-object-is-a-member-of-a-collection-in-vba)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to do a count of distinct values within a specified column of an array, here is an example with a 5*3 array read in from a worksheet range, counting the distinct values in column 2. I am using a function by [Mark Nold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137845/determining-whether-an-object-is-a-member-of-a-collection-in-vba) to check if the value to be added already exists in the collection.

```
Option Explicit
    
Public Sub test()

    Dim testArr()
    Dim myCount As Long

    testArr = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C5").Value

    myCount = CountUarrcol(testArr, 2)

    MsgBox myCount

End Sub

Public Function CountUarrcol(inarr() As Variant, colidx As Long) As Long

    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To UBound(inarr)
        
        If Not InCollection(col, CStr(inarr(i, colidx))) Then
       
            col.Add Item:=CStr(inarr(i, colidx)), key:=CStr(inarr(i, colidx))
        
        End If
   
    Next i
 
    CountUarrcol = col.Count
 
End Function

'Mark Nold  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137845/determining-whether-an-object-is-a-member-of-a-collection-in-vba
 
Public Function InCollection(col As Collection, key As String) As Boolean
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim errNumber As Long

    InCollection = False
    Set var = Nothing

    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
    var = col.Item(key)
    errNumber = CLng(Err.Number)
    On Error GoTo 0

    '5 is not in, 0 and 438 represent incollection
    If errNumber = 5 Then                        ' it is 5 if not in collection
        InCollection = False
    Else
        InCollection = True
    End If

End Function
```

[image: Running macro]

Answer (score 0):

I Used two sub routine as follow:

```
Public Function CountUvalinarrcol(ByRef inarr As Variant, ByVal colidx As Integer) As Long
     Dim col As New Collection
     Dim i As Integer
     Dim element As Variant
                         
     For i = 1 To UBound(inarr)
     element = inarr(i, colidx)

         If colContains(col, element) = False Then
            col.Add item:=CStr(element)
         End If
     Next i
     CountUvalinarrcol = col.Count
End Function
```

The other one is:

```
    Public Function colContains(colin As Collection, itemin As Variant) As Boolean
Dim item As Variant
  colContains = False
  For Each item In colin
    If item = itemin Then
      colContains = True
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

Calling above functions:

```
sub test()
dim x as long
x= CountUvalinarrcol(lsarr, 0)
end sub
```